# how to use farbric8 connects to connect to the Kubernetes API within a Pod

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

As we know, fabric can connect Kubernetes via ~/.kube/config file. I am wondering how to use farbric8 connects to connect to the Kubernetes API within a Pod? Is there any fabric8 API/library support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from Fabric8 team. Fabric8 Kubernetes Client automatically detects whether it's inside a Pod or outside.

- When inside the cluster, Fabric8 Kubernetes Client reads Kubernetes API token and ceritificates from ServiceAccount mounted inside the Pod(`/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`). Api server URL is determined by reading `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable.
- When outside the cluster, it just reads `.kube/config` as usual.

To end user, the process should be transparent. Just make sure your Pod's ServiceAccount has correct roles assigned to access some api group.

I had tested this some time ago on a demo project with minikube and it was working okay for me. You can try it out and see if it helps your use case: https://github.com/rohanKanojia/kubernetes-client-inside-pod